# How to use nativeElement.focus() with each unique input inside ngFor in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a ngFor loop as below.

```
<div *ngFor= "let transporter of transporters">
    <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]= "transporter.name" #inputTransporter *ngIf="openTransporterFreightEditing">
    <mat-icon class="cursor-btn"  (click)="openEdit()">mode_edit</mat-icon>
</div>
```

And the TS code:

```
 openTransporterFreightEditing:boolean = false
@ViewChild('inputTransporter') inputTransporter: ElementRef;

openEdit() {
    this.openTransporterFreightEditing = true
    this.inputTransporter.nativeElement.focus()
}
```

The input field is at first hidden. When the edit symbol is clicked the input becomes visible. I want to focus the input as soon as it becomes visible. However,I want to focus on one particular input by using nativeElement.focus(), but I am facing difficulty because of the same ID "inputTransporter" in each input element created by the loop. 
How do I focus one particular input ID based on (click). If I have to generate unique ID for each element I may have to use `[attr.id]` which isn't working with `@ViewChild` .

My code in stackblitz :

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4hedvr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `@ViewChildren` to access an array of `QueryList`.

You may pass the `index` to your `openEdit` function and access the required native element and then focus it.

For a demo sample on how to access the children, please refer to the below link:-

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sgudix?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let a of [1,2,3]; let i=index">
      <p #para>Para {{a}}</p>
    <button (click)="colorMe(i)">Color Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  @ViewChildren('para') paras: any;
  paraElements: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.paraElements = this.paras.map(para => {
      console.log('Paras: ', para.nativeElement);
      return para.nativeElement;
    })
  }

  colorMe(index) {
    console.log('Index: ', index);
    this.paraElements[index].style.backgroundColor = '#5789D8';
  }
```

This should give you a good idea on how to implement it at your end.

Hope it helps.

**PS: Somethings are not as per standard like declaring variables inside HTML, using `any` type, etc. as it was a rough demo application to just give an idea.**

Comment: I am just getting started with angular, can you explain a little how can I use the index in focus() ?

Comment: Ok, i'll help you in the demo code. Give me few minutes.

Comment: Please check, I have made a sample where in you can colour your paragraphs. Do it in the same way to focus your input. Let me know if it helps now.

Comment: error is coming as "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". paras variable is not filling when the component is initialised

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for it so that we can provide you a solution for your code?

Comment: Here is my code in stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4hedvr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Please use something like in the following stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhfr6w?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: While I am trying to implement it, an error is coming : "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". any idea why it might be there? on the component load "this.transporterId" is comming as undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176393/discussion-between-udg-and-ankit-sharma).